# Is there a better way to run this mysql update?

Tags: mysql, insert

I have the following code, which firstly retrieves each unique style from a database and then searches through the products table to find the terms associated with each style and updates the stylerefs table with the styleid and the productid:

```
$query = "Select id,style,terms from su_styles";

if ($results = $sudb->query($query)) {

while($result = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

      $id=$result['id'];
      $style=$result['style'];
      $terms=$result['terms'];      

$query= "INSERT IGNORE INTO su_stylerefs (mykey,id) 
    SELECT mykey,$id FROM su_pref where (match(name) against ('$terms' in Boolean Mode)) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=$id, mykey = su_pref.mykey";     

$sudb->query($query);
```

Is there anyway I can rewrite this query into one, rather than looping through the results of the first query?  I have 10 other similar queries that need to run every day and some of the tables in the first query could have 100s of records, which mean hundreds of connections to the database, which takes a while.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would fetch all these rows first along with the match() case, and then do an update:

```
INSERT INTO su_stylerefs (mykey, id)
VALUES ($mykey[0], $id[0]), ($mykey[1] $id[1]), ...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=$id, mykey = su_pref.mykey
```

**2nd solution:**

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO su_stylerefs (mykey,id) 
SELECT sp.mykey, ss.id
FROM su_styles AS ss
INNER JOIN su_pref AS sp
ON match(sp.name) against (ss.terms in Boolean Mode)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = VALUES(id), mykey = VALUES(mykey)
```

This may be a better solution.

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for your answer, but what if I have 50,000 records returned from the select? Will this solution work efficiently?

Comment: 2nd solution given that may improve in your case.

Comment: Thanks @Robin Castlin, but I get the following error 'Incorrect arguments to AGAINST'. I did a little research and there appears to be an issue with using a field in a full text search.  Any ideas how to get round this?

Comment: The manual clearly states `The search string must be a literal string, not a variable or a column name.`

Comment: Okay, I guess that makes sence. I can't see how this is performed efficiently withtout using JOINS. @Amara Are you sure you've made the best possible structure for your system?

Comment: Well I have the three tables a product table, a category table and a table which links the two.  Isn't this the best way to do it?

Comment: Could you make a connection between these that didn't rely on a `MATCH()`? IDs or key names, that is. Then this could be done with a similiar and reliable query.

Comment: No I create the connection using the match.